# 404 error with python on apache2

Tags: python, apache2

I have a file `test.py` at `/var/www` and I am using `apache2` on ubuntu 10.10. I have `mod_python` installed and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` configured as

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    AddHandler mod_python .py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
    PythonDebug On

    # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
    # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
    #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>
```

If it put

```
def index(req):
  return "Test successful";
```

Then i get `Test successful`

And if i put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

I get `404: Not found` error

More can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34338/error-while-configuring-python-in-apache2)

Anyone any ideas ??

Regards,

experimentX

Comment: And if you put that what? What is your question exactly?

Comment: Thanks! Had a similar problem trying to get a downloaded Python script to run (my first Python encounter) and this question got me into the right direction: `print` versus `def index(req):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_python looks for  method `def index(req)` by default when it tries to handle your requests, otherwise you can specify the function which you want to call in the URL. Note that function has to return a specific value.

So you can do something like

```
s ="""\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""

def index():
   return s
```

The url travelsal under mod_python is [illustrated here.](http://webpython.codepoint.net/mod_python_publisher_uri_traversal)

Comment: @experimentX - Try to read the article that I hyperlinked. It has some good details on mod_wsgi as well to help you get started. Btw, mod_python is not bad, only thing is it is old and probably dead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mod_python` I would suggest you to use `mod_wsgi` as there are many WSGI-using frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), etc...

Cool thing with these frameworks is that you don't even have to use the Apache on your development machine, but instead can use their builtin test-server.

Comment: still, ... i come from php. and would feel better if i am able to do so.

Comment: @experimentX: Well, mod_python has been sort of deprecated since WSGI protocol and mod_wsgi came out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_python#Problems

Comment: i see .. will installing and enabling `mod_wsgi` solve my problem and  how to disables `mod_python`